# Turn array into comma separated grammatically correct sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

If I have an array in Javascript that looks like

```
searchComponents = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3'];
```

What is the necessary logic to turn it into a sentence like:

"element1, element2, and element3"

Likewise, if there are only two elements it should read like:

"element1 and element2"

and so on and so forth. I am stuck.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: It is considered bad form (by some) to put a comma before "and" ([*Oxford/Harvard comma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)).

Comment: Probably you want to use [*join*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5) with ", " (comma followed by a space), then replace the last comma with " and" (space followed by the word "and").

Comment: @RobG: Whether the serial comma is considered "bad form" or not clearly depends on which side of that particular fence you're on.

Comment: @GregHewgill—updated comment (link also explains it). :-)

Comment: Who needs to think when you can just come to StackOverflow and have someone write your code for you.

Comment: @cookiemonster—a few lines of code for an *ad hoc* function is not an issue. Something non–trivial, say an event handling framework, is another matter. :-)

Comment: @RobG: Or a homework assignment or test?

Comment: simply stuck on correct logic, i've been out of the school environment for a bit now;) @cookiemonster...no need to insinuate

Answer (score 28):

One easy solution:

```
function arrayToSentence (arr) {
    var last = arr.pop();
    return arr.join(', ') + ' and ' + last;
}

console.log(arrayToSentence(['one','two','three']));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4E8Bt/).

And a slightly more complex/ridiculous solution (because who doesn't like silly, occasionally...):

```
function arrayToSentence (arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    return arr.reduce(function(a,b,c){
        return a + (c - 1 === length ? ', ' : ' and ') + b;
    });
}

console.log(arrayToSentence(['one','two','three']));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4E8Bt/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Be sure to check if the array is a single value! Or you may end up with " and one".

Comment: @Laugh: that seems like a feature, not a bug? (Depending on what comes before this 'sentence' structure.)

Comment: @DavidThomas It wouldn't seem to make grammatical sense if there was 1 item in the list, and part of a sentence. As far as other parts of the same sentence is concerned, other checks will need to be made for plurality, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @DavidThomas The "complex/ridiculous" solution seems to have some mistakes. You'll see in the fiddle it doesn't work with any number of items other than 3. I've updated the fiddle here to what I believe will work: http://jsfiddle.net/4E8Bt/6/

Comment: okay, so it seems the fiddle's don't reflect the actual code from this answer (after being edited).

Answer (score 23):

```
function toSentence(arr) {
  return arr.slice(0, -2).join(', ') + 
    (arr.slice(0, -2).length ? ', ' : '') + 
    arr.slice(-2).join(' and ');
}
```

usage

```
toSentence([1])
```

**1**

```
toSentence([1, 2])
```

**1 and 2**

```
toSentence([1, 2, 3])
```

**1, 2 and 3**

```
toSentence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

**1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6**

Comment: Very neat! For anyone wanting to include the Oxford/Serial Comma, you can just add it before the " and "

Comment: @rubie wouldn't that result in `1, and 2` ?

Comment: Oh dear, good spot @animatedgif - I guess could change it to [...]`.join(arr.length === 2 ? " and " : ", and ")` - think that would work

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one liner:

```js
const arrayToSentence = (a) => [a.slice(0, -1).join(', '), a.pop()].filter(w => w !== '').join(' and ');

console.log(arrayToSentence(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']));
console.log(arrayToSentence(['foo', 'bar']));
console.log(arrayToSentence(['foo']));
console.log(arrayToSentence([]));
```

Comment: Oooh, 'run code snippet!' New and shiny! Very nice! I like the chaining you used as well.

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but this is my attempt at it. Relatively simple, immutable arguments, and works for 0-N items.

```js
const toListSentence = (arr) => arr.length < 3 ?
  arr.join(' and ') :
  `${arr.slice(0, -1).join(', ')}, and ${arr[arr.length - 1]}`;

console.log(toListSentence([]));
console.log(toListSentence(['apple']));
console.log(toListSentence(['apple', 'banana']));
console.log(toListSentence(['apple', 'banana', 'peach']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try my compound-subject library:

https://github.com/adamshaylor/compound-subject

It includes controls over what character to delimit with (e.g. commas versus semicolons) as well as whether to delimit all the subjects (i.e. the “Oxford comma”).

Answer (score 2):

More ES6/7 version without mutation:

```
function buildSentence (arr = []) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  }

  const newArr = [...arr];
  const last = newArr.pop();    
  return newArr.join(', ') + ' and ' + last;
}
buildSentence([]);
buildSentence(['a']);
buildSentence(['a', 'b']);
buildSentence(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Comment: Love this! The question's requested output includes the Oxford comma (comma after second to last item, if more than 2), so I would make this change, which also takes advantage of ES6 template literals (pretend the single quotes on the ends are backticks, due to minimarkdown limitations!): 
`return '${newArr.join(', ')}${newArr > 1 ? ',' : ''} and ${last}';`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a typed version that utilizes lodash functions:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-architecture-z1854?file=/src/App.js

```
import { concat, first, join, last, slice } from 'lodash'

function joinOxford (list: string[]): string {
  switch (list.length) {
  case 1: return first(list)
  case 2: return `${first(list)} and ${last(list)}`
  default: return join(concat(slice(list, 0, -1), [`and ${last(list)}`]), ', ')
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
joinOxford(['Alona'])
// Alona

joinOxford(['Alona', 'Loyce'])
// Alona and Loyce

joinOxford(['Alona', 'Loyce', 'Mikel'])
// Alona, Loyce, and Mikel

joinOxford(['Alona', 'Loyce', 'Mikel', 'Carrie'])
// Alona, Loyce, Mikel, and Carrie

joinOxford(['Alona', 'Loyce', 'Mikel', 'Carrie', 'Josie'])
// Alona, Loyce, Mikel, Carrie, and Josie
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this...

```
function parseArray(arr) {
    var s=arr.toString();
    var c=s.lastIndexOf(",");
    if(c!=-1) s=(s.substr(0,c)+" and "+s.substr(c+1)).replace(/,/g,", ");
return s[0].toUpperCase()+s.substr(1)+".";
}

console.log(parseArray(["one", "two","three","four","five"]));
console.log(parseArray(["one", "two"]));
console.log(parseArray(["one"]));
```

Output is:

```
One, two, three, four and five.
One and two.
One.
```

Grammatically correct?